# Pandas DataFrame.groupby().agg() issue

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I'm trying to use pandas groupby().agg() but I have some issues.

```
Date               Year Month Week Hour A   B       C   D         E   F  G ..
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  5   6   6   144,79  0   868,74    6   36
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  6   214 214 144,79  0   30985,0   6   214
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  6   6   6   144,79  0   868,74    6   36
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  7   220 220 180,26  0   39657,2   220 48
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  7   100 100 180,26  146 18026     100 10
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  8   220 220 225,2   0   49544     220 48
mercoledì 5 aprile 2023 4   14  8   57  57  2,2     146 129,38    6   57
```

I have to sum some columns (and that goes with agg({'column':sum}), do a weighted average on others, with the weights being in a column, and have to mean() the remaining columns.

```
df = df.groupby(['Date','Hour']).agg({'A':'sum', 
                                      'B':'sum',
                                      'C': weighted average?, 
                                      'D':'sum', 
                                      'E':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

I wanna do the weighted average on C, and the weights are the values in column B.

Then, for the non-indicated columns in .agg() (F,G, and so on, I have many of them) I wanna apply the method .mean(), keeping all the columns in the end.

Can you help me?
Thank you

Tried this:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date','Hour']).agg({'A':'sum', 
                                      'B':'sum',
                                      'C': weighted average?, 
                                      'D':'sum', 
                                      'E':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

But I don't know how to properly code it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Date": ["mercoledì 5 aprile 2023", "mercoledì 5 aprile 2023", "mercoledì 5 aprile 2023", "mercoledì 5 aprile 2023", "mercoledì 5 aprile 2023", "mercoledì 5 aprile 2023"],
    "Year": [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    "Month": [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    "Week": [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
    "Hour": [5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8],
    "A": [6, 214, 6, 220, 100, 220],
    "B": [6, 214, 6, 220, 100, 57],
    "C": [144.79, 144.79, 144.79, 180.26, 180.26, 2.2],
    "D": [0, 0, 0, 0, 146, 146],
    "E": [868.74, 30985.0, 868.74, 39657.2, 18026.0, 129.38],
    "F": [6, 214, 36, 48, 10, 57],
    "G": [36, 214, 36, 48, 10, 57],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)



# Calculate sum of A, mean of B, and weighted mean of C using B as weights
result = df.groupby(['Date','Hour']).agg({
'A': 'sum', 
'B': 'sum',
'C': lambda x: (df['B'] * df['C']).sum() / df['B'].sum(),
'D': 'sum', 
'E': 'mean'
})

print(result.reset_index())

Date  Hour    A    B           C    D         E
0  mercoledì 5 aprile 2023     5    6    6  150.134561    0    868.74
1  mercoledì 5 aprile 2023     6  220  220  150.134561    0  15926.87
2  mercoledì 5 aprile 2023     7  320  320  150.134561  146  28841.60
3  mercoledì 5 aprile 2023     8  220   57  150.134561  146    129.38
```

Comment: This will recompute the **whole** operation for **each** group! Also as this is a side effect, the operation cannot be used in a chain of commands or it will risk to use incorrect data. I strongly advise against this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute a weighted average with `agg` directly as this requires two columns*.

One way would be to pre-/post-process the computation. The weighted average is equal to `sum(C*B)/sum(B)`:

```
out = (df.eval('C = C*B')
         .groupby(['Date', 'Hour'])
         .agg({'A': 'sum', 
               'B': 'sum',
               'C': 'sum', 
               'D': 'sum', 
               'E': 'mean'})
         .eval('C = C/B')
         .reset_index()
     )
```

*NB. If you were already computing a different aggregation with B/C you would need to use copies of them.*

To handle all columns you can use a dictionary:

```
d = {c: 'mean' for c in df.columns.difference(['Date', 'Hour'])}
for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    d[c] = 'sum'

out = (df.eval('C = C*B')
         .groupby(['Date', 'Hour'], as_index=False)
         .agg(d)
         .eval('C = C/B')
     )
```

* you can however compute the weighted average with `groupby.apply`, but this should be done as a separate operation.

Comment: I'm gonna  try using the second code. What happens if B has a 0 value? How can i handle the division by 0 error?

Comment: @wingS pandas should take care of that for you and yield a NaN, else you can use a `where` clause.